# Code does not work in Xcode, but it works fine in NetBeans?

Tags: c, xcode, netbeans, struct

I spend hours trying to find the error in my school exercise, and it seems that my code doesn't work in Xcode, but it does work in NetBeans.

How is that possible and what can I do to make it work in Xcode? I can not debug in NetBeans, and that's the main reason why I changed to Apple's Xcode...

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char naam[20];
    int leeftijd;
} persoon;
persoon Jorn;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("Uw naam: ");
    scanf("%s", Jorn.naam);
    printf("Leeftijd:");
    scanf("%d", &Jorn.leeftijd);
    printf("\n Inhoud");

    return 0;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

My variable "leeftijd" remains empty.

[image]

Comment: What does *not work* mean, **exactly**? Does it compile, do you get a runtime error, or is the output not what you expected?

Comment: It compiles, but it stops working after i fill in "leeftijd". The printf with "inhoud" does not appear in the compiler...

Answer (score 1):

The program is fine. The output goes to the lldb window and enter the text there too.

Here is a sample run.

> Uw naam: Dan
>   Leeftijd:Zaph

Create a Project for Command Line Tool:

[image]

[image]

I added the following two lines:

```
printf("naam: %s\n", Jorn.naam);
printf("leeftijd: %d\n", Jorn.leeftijd);
```

Output:

> naam: Dan
>   leeftijd: 34

Comment: Thanks Zaph,but i did it completely like you're print screens. Can it be a setting in Xcode?

Comment: I would like to post a print screen, but i do not have enough reputation to do it, sucks!

Comment: Also, if i manually stop the compiler, it says "Program ended with exit code: 9". Normally, it says, Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: Take a screen shot, post somewhere on the net, add the link to your post or a comment, I will edit your question to post the image. I just created a new project, copied the code from this question, replaced the code in main, ran and it worked. So there is doe other difference.

Comment: Thanks for taking time for me Zaph, here is the link to the screenshot! [link]http://debobanden.be/xcode.png Another screenshot with breakpoint (My variable "leeftijd" remains empty???) http://debobanden.be/xcode2.png

Comment: You have breakpoints, remove them. If you are still having problems create a whole new Xcode project: File:New:Project... not just a new target. When ever you are having difficulties simplify.

Comment: I already made a completely new project, still doesn't work, i also removed all breakpoints... This is the weirest problem i ever had in my programming career! :p Maybe reinstall xcode?

Comment: Zaph, i think i found the problem, but i still don't understand why it works in netbeans and not in Xcode. the variable "leeftijd" means in english age. If you fill in a number by "leeftijd", it won't work normally.... If i type letters by leetijd, the code runs without a problem! http://www.debobanden.be/xcode4.png

Comment: It looks like the program is running. Add some printf statements to display the data you entered. I added: `printf("naam: %s\n", Jorn.naam);` `printf("leeftijd: %d\n", Jorn.leeftijd);`

Comment: It seems to work now! I changed nothing in my code, i just slept a night, tried it now and it works! Very strange! Thanks anyway for you're efforts! Jorn